# Adding Ctrl key to autohotkey combination

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have this simple hot key to mute the volume

`ScrollLock::Send {Volume_Mute}`

It works but I want to add the `Ctrl` key so that I have to press `Ctrl` + `ScrollLock` to activate `{Volume_Mute}`. How do you do it?

I tried `^ScrollLock::Send {Volume_Mute}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotkeys can be triggered by using the 3-digit hexadecimal **scan code (SC)** of a key:

```
; Ctrl + ScrollLock
^SC046::Send {Volume_Mute}
```

in the rare case where a key has no name or the standard code doesn't work.

The scan code of a key can be determined by following the steps at [**Special Keys**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys):

> - Run a script with keyboard hook
> - open the AutoHotkey window (context    menu in systray, Open item)
> - go to View > Key History and script info
> - type the key
> - hit F5 to see the code

Comment: That worked but I forgot to mention that I have a previous hotkey also for `ScrollLock`. Basically, I need this `ScrollLock::Send {Volume_Down}` and another hotkey with `Ctrl` like that of yours `^SC046::Send {Volume_Mute}`. Is that possible?

Comment: Try `SC046::Send {Volume_Down}`(replace all ScrollLock with SC046 in the script).